# Extra Figure in Matplotlib Animation using Smopy

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to create an animated map plot using smopy and matplotlib in jupyter, but when I run the code I get two figures instead of one.  The first figure is shown above the map and empty.  Can anyone tell me how to fix this so that only the animation is drawn?

```
import smopy
import matplotlib.animation as animation

n= 1000
%matplotlib notebook

def update(curr):
    if curr == n-100:
        a.event_source.stop()
    lons = crime_df.X[curr:curr+100]
    lats = crime_df.Y[curr:curr+100]
    x,y = map.to_pixels(lats,lons)
    ax.scatter(x, y, c='r', alpha=0.7, s=200)
    plt.title(curr)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = smopy.Map((37.6624,-122.5168,37.8231,-122.3589), z=12)
ax = ax.show_mpl(figsize=(8,8))
a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create an additional figure, if that is undersired: Leave out `plt.figure()`.

```
import smopy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

n= 1000
%matplotlib notebook

def update(curr):
    if curr == n-100:
        a.event_source.stop()
    lons = crime_df.X[curr:curr+100]
    lats = crime_df.Y[curr:curr+100]
    x,y = map.to_pixels(lats,lons)
    ax.scatter(x, y, c='r', alpha=0.7, s=200)
    plt.title(curr)


m = smopy.Map((37.6624,-122.5168,37.8231,-122.3589), z=12)
ax = m.show_mpl(figsize=(8,8))
a = animation.FuncAnimation(ax.figure, update, interval=100)
```

Alternatively create the figure beforehands,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
m = smopy.Map((37.6624,-122.5168,37.8231,-122.3589), z=12)
m.show_mpl(ax = ax)
a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  I had tried FuncAnimation(ax, update) before but that caused an error.